# Convert list(s) to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

*#Lists generated from User input.*

```
user1_name = ['Adam']
user1_passion = ['Coding','Wood Chopping','Sleeping']
user2_name = ['Eve']
user2_passion = ['Coding','Eating Apples','Sleeping']
```

How do I convert the above to a nested dictionary like this?

```
user_info = {
    'user1': {
        'fname': 'adam',
        'passion': ['coding', 'wood chopping', 'sleeping']
    },
    'user2': {
        'fname': 'eve',
        'passion': ['coding', 'eating apples', 'sleeping']
    },

}
```

Comment: Hi! Please edit your question and add a [mcve] _of what you've tried and doesn't work._ This is an extremely straightforward use of dict: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Why does `"Wood Chopping"` become `"hunting"`?

Comment: Note that a better plan is to create the dict in the format you want right from the beginning.  Don't accumulate the data first.

Comment: @msanford - Hi. I did refer to the docs and for the level of expertise that I have in Python, I could not,on my own, figure out how to convert the values I have into dictionaries.

Comment: @ddejohn If you don't do house chores like cutting wood, you better do something else, something more physical, like hunting.

Comment: @ddejohn on a more serious note, there are two different users, user1 and user2, with different variables holding the list of their passions.

Comment: I see that, but `user1` is `Adam` and one of their passions is listed as `Wood Chopping` but in your desired dictionary structure, it changes to `hunting`. Looks like a typo.

Comment: Seems like the outer container could be a list, not a dict, assuming  the names `user1` and `user2` aren't significant.

Comment: @Display_name could you share the code that collects the input from the users?  The answer to your question is going to involve just undoing whatever that code did; it would be easier to see the original code and "fix" it to put everything in the right place up front.

Comment: As Tim and Samwise both mention, if possible it would be much easier to do this at the time of gathering user input.

Comment: @ddejohn thank you! it indeed was a typo. Have edited the question.

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts Samwise ddejohn and msanford - so you guys are saying, if I happen to find myself with this data, stored in lists (let's presume I cannot alter it in anyway), there is no way to convert this data set into dictionary?

Comment: @Display_name Of course there is a way to convert it.  It's trivial.  The issue is, if you really only have two names, then it's silly to worry about this.  It's a simple manual operation.  We ASSUME that you will actually have many more names to worry about, in which case you would not store them in individual variables, and you should change the way you do input.

Comment: @martineau well it seems like for making an honest attempt at coding, you need to have a certain familiarity with what you have been coding, but for many of us neophytes, its not always the case and when someone like me posts question here, why should you or anyone assume not enough attempts have been made to solve the problem by the person asking the question. Rather than unwittingly implying that I see StackOverflow and its community as a free-coding-service, I would much appreciate it if you share solutions to the problem I posted as I have failed to come up with a solution on my own.

Comment: @TimRoberts I appreciate your feedback, but to what might be trivial for you, is definitely not trivial for me, hence I posted the question here. I could very well use the methodology of the answer posted here, scale it up if the situation so arises where I have to handle a larger data set with similar problem structure.

Comment: @martineau Duly noted. But did receive some answers already. That is reasonable enough for me to keep asking questions here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to wrangle these lists into a dict by doing something like:

```
>>> user_info = {
...     f"user{i}": {
...         'fname': name[0].lower(),
...         'passion': [p.lower() for p in passion]
...     }  for i, (name, passion) in enumerate(
...        [(user1_name, user1_passion), (user2_name, user2_passion)],
...        1
...     )
... }
>>>
>>> user_info
{'user1': {'fname': 'adam', 'passion': ['coding', 'wood chopping', 'sleeping']}, 'user2': {'fname': 'eve', 'passion': ['coding', 'eating apples', 'sleeping']}}
```

It would be much simpler if these pieces of input weren't in different statically-named variables in the first place though; the easy solution is to just insert them into a dictionary (or list) as you gather the input.

For example:

```
>>> num_users = 2
>>> user_info = {
...     f"user{i}": {
...         'fname': input("User name: ").lower(),
...         'passion': input("What are your passions?  (Comma-separated list.) ").lower().split(",")
...     } for i in range(1, num_users+1)
... }
User name: Adam
What are your passions?  (Comma-separated list.) Coding,Wood Chopping,Sleeping
User name: Eve
What are your passions?  (Comma-separated list.) Coding,Eating Apples,Sleeping
>>> user_info
{'user1': {'fname': 'adam', 'passion': ['coding', 'wood chopping', 'sleeping']}, 'user2': {'fname': 'eve', 'passion': ['coding', 'eating apples', 'sleeping']}}
```

Comment: Thank you @Samwise, Ill try this solution in my IDE.